# What kind of lock used to be here?

Tags: lock, locks

We're moving into a new place and have been told by the building's management that the top lock on our door is our own responsibility. It appears that the previous tenants had something in the top lock position and took it with them (or the building removed it after they moved out). I have pictures of what I am talking about, and I would be very grateful if anyone could tell me (a) what kind of lock used to be here? and (b) what other kinds of locks, if any, can we put on our door considering we don't want to have to put a hole in the door frame (see last picture).

[image: Here's a close-up of where the 6" tall by 4" wide plate used to be, with a hole drilled through the door and various screw holes.]

[image: Side view of the door showing that there is no place (anymore? ever?) for the bolt to go through the side of the door to reach the door frame.]

[image: A view from the hallway. They can see us in our apartment!]

[image: It looks like there used to be some sort of 1" wide thing that was drilled onto the door frame on the inside of the apartment, and that perhaps whatever sort of bolt came out of whatever was mounted on that 6" by 4" plate went into this device on the door frame here.]

[image: A view from the side of the door frame showing again that there is no place in the door frame for a bolt to go into, even if it could get through the side of the door (which it couldn't, at least now). At the bottom of the frame you can see where the bottom lock goes into the frame.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like they had a "jimmy-proof deadbolt" on the door. You should be able to pickup one at any major hardware store.

[image]

Comment: Perfect -- that seems to be exactly it! And I believe these things are all over our neighborhood -- shoulda known!

Comment: The widely spaced holes suggest that large security plates were also installed. These reinforce the door against a brute force attack on the door and the lock.